# Android Studio custom button color is not changing while shape is changing

Tags: android, android-layout

I added a custom button, changed some values for every state but still when I press the button the button is not changing, and just getting the default style, I changed the shape in form rectangle to oval so I can see if in selector does it enter to the pressed state and I see it does enter now the only problem is the solid or the color that its not changing.

custom button implementation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_enabled="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/LightGray"/>
        <corners android:radius="200dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <color android:color="@color/Blue"/>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="200dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/DarkBlue"/>
        <corners android:radius="200dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

and Button implementation:

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_width="102dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
    android:text="Next >"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   />
```

Comment: add java code to see the OnclickListener

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I  figured out that when using the custom  button make  sure to change the

```
<Button.../>
```

**to**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
```

It's due to material io buttons can't accept custom buttons as background.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with position of the color in pressed state. Solid color property should be inside  tag. Try using below

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/Blue"/>   <-- Move inside Shape
        <corners android:radius="200dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

And it should work as expected.

If above is not working then try creating different drawable for different state:

1. Enabled false: drawable_1

   ```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

            <corners android:radius="8dp" />

            <solid android:color="@color/LightGray" />
    </shape>
   ```
2. Pressed True: drawable_2

   ```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

            <corners android:radius="8dp" />

            <solid android:color="@color/Blue" />
    </shape>
   ```
3. Pressed False: drawable_3

   ```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

            <corners android:radius="8dp" />

            <solid android:color="@color/DarkBlue" />
        </shape>
   ```
4. Finally combine all drawables with selector

   ```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_1" android:state_enabled ="true"></item>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_2" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_3" android:state_pressed="false"></item>

    </selector>
   ```

Comment: still it's not working, I tried all the possibilities such using solid, using it as BG or tint but non of them are worked... I need help please

Comment: Updated answer. Try it out. and update some minor flags to toggle states.

Comment: I tried again these all that you said but it does not work, just like before,  when I hover over the button where I set the Background to a drawable resource fille it shows a 3 lines which all have in RED color, those are the links that is connected to any state, nothing else

Comment: also the same. code is working in one of my early 2020 project which I worked with Java, but in this project I used Kotlin.

Comment: and I also checked that its not working when I create a new project whether its using Kotlin or Java, just working on the previously created project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this one

change the theme

-> From This

```
<style name="Theme.Dark"parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">   
</style>
```

-> To This

```
<style name="Theme.Dark"parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">   
</style>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).